# Are female police officers one-sixth as likely to kill as their male colleagues?

Tags: united-states, statistics, police, demographics, gender

The incidence of people dying due to use of force by the police is a high profile issue at the moment.  Figures about the distribution of these deaths, such as found in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6080222/), can be compared to population statistics to demonstrate how different demographics are affected at different rates to those of the general population.

We can also compare the demographics of the officers involved in these deaths (table 6) to the [demographics of the police force as a whole](https://datausa.io/profile/soc/police-officers), and see the features that are overrepresented.  For example 67% of police are white but 84.3% of officers involved with the deaths are, indicating a hazard ratio of 2.  However the largest effect I have found is that of sex, in that males make up 84.9% of police but account for 97.4% of deaths, indicating a hazard ratio of 5.8.

Does this represent the true risk, in that your chance of dying in an encounter with the police is nearly 6 times greater if that police officer is male compared to female, or is there another explanation?  For example, a policy of assigning female officers to lower risk areas or roles would explain this observation.

Comment: The study uses the FBI’s Uniform Crime Reporting Program, the CDC’s National Vital Statistics System and the CDC’s National Violent Death Reporting System.  It is purely focused on the deaths that happened, it makes no speculation about what would happen without police.  This question is focused on the characteristics of the police, not those who died.  If there was any indication about the cause of the downvotes I may be able to do something about it.

Comment: Your question is fine if it wasn't based on a specific group's conflict with the police, and suggested the conclusion that there were problems with the police based solely on that conflict. You might need to edit your write-up to include evidence of the conflict between the police and the entire society as a whole to justify your question. Also, include examples that female officers cause less policing problems and death than male.

Comment: Do you mean that using the example of the rate at which black people die from police use of force in the 1st paragraph makes the whole thing "based on a specific group's conflict with the police"?  I included it to show how these numbers are commonly used, not to indicate that that is in any way related to the question, and have now edited it.  I do not think examples would help, this is a question about the numbers in aggregate.  I cannot imagine what the examples you ask for would be, I do not have them.

Comment: To me, those number is twisted but been used to justify the need in improving the relationship and image of police with that group. It has nothing to do with your question if you don't bother to broaden the scope.

Comment: Which number?  I have used the article from the highest impact factor peer reviewed journal could find.  My question is very specifically about how one should interpret the findings of the study.  I say nothing about improving the relationship and image of police.

Comment: I see you have edited the write-up of your question to exclude the problematic FBI data which was my concern. I am going to reverse my downvote then.

Comment: This seems like a question that is intended to push a point. Underrepresentation of women could be *a* dangerous thing, but the question seems framed to suggest that police brutality and police racism are, at most, minor problems in comparison.

Comment: That is certainly not my intention.  It is the under representation of women in causing death by use of force compared to in the police as a whole that is in question.  If it is true that women are less likely to kill than men in the same situation then that would suggest that police brutality and police racism is a function of the police, as opposed to the victim, and therefore could be dealt with by changes in the police.  My question is if this is an appropriate interpretation of the data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on Skeptics.

Comment: "that would suggest that police brutality and police racism is a function of the police" um, yes?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I agree. Saying "police are political" at the beginning is not enough to make this a political question. If lawmakers were actively debating the merits of an all-female police force, then it would be relevant to ask if their arguments were backed by evidence. But that's not the current state of affairs.

Comment: If my question was "are these numbers correct" then sceptics would be better.  My question is more "are there policies that cause this, rather than men being more likely to kill people in any given situation", which seems to be political to me.

Comment: I'd note that the number of police killings is quite low (in the low hundreds) per year so you'd expect significant variation from averages simply due to random variation - probably not enough to explain the disparity but probably enough to make the true magnitude of the disparity after considering potential random variation very uncertain.

Comment: I agree with @ohwilleke is that for crime reporting statistics, the number of police related deaths is two low for the numbers to be indicative of a statistical trend, let alone  if the numbers in your data set control for the subset of police involve deaths of suspects that were deemed not justified by the agency's "Use of Force" policy and relevant training.

Answer (score 9):

> Does this represent the true risk, in that your chance of dying in an encounter with the police is nearly 6 times greater if that police officer is male compared to female, or is there another explanation?

Female officers are vastly underrepresented in SWAT teams and other special teams designated to go after the very highest risk criminals (I am unable to find any actual numbers for this, but searching 'female SWAT officer' reveals a number of articles describing such an officer as the only female SWAT officer in her department).

Thus, the correlation is true, but the implied causation is backwards. If you are a barricaded suspect, have hostages, have an outstanding warrant for murder, etc. the officers sent to disarm you and bring you in will almost certainly be male. Given that you allowed things to escalate to that point without peacefully surrendering, the odds that when the officers make their move, that you'll represent a mortal threat and thus get shot is high.

The implied causation in your question is not addressed in the paper you linked, as it makes no attempt to account for victim behavior nor circumstances (at least as it relates to its discussion of the demographics of officers). However, there is an interesting tidbit that addresses a different point in your question:

> Ridgeway compared shooting and non-shooting officers at the same scene (using data from 106 officer-involved shootings in New York City) and found that black officers...were more likely to shoot

Thus, despite white officers without normalization having a hazard ratio of 2 (per your question), black officers are more likely to shoot when on the same scene. Looking at [Ridgeway](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/2330443X.2015.1129918) we can see that they did look at the sex of the officer. While they found an odds ratio of 2.1, with a p-value of 0.29, it is very far from statistically significant. Given the low likelihood of a female officer at a shooting scene, it would almost certainly take a far larger sample than Ridgeway looked at to tease out the actual difference in risk.

Even Ridgeway has the confounding factor of victim behavior. Is there perhaps still a subconscious chivalrous behavior that reduces the likelihood of victims to have attempted to shoot at female officers vs their male colleagues?

Thus, **all else being equal**, are you six times more likely to be shot by a male officer than a female officer? Almost certainly not. Is there a somewhat higher risk? Very difficult to tell and I would be dubious of any study that claimed it had a definitive answer.

Comment: There are also police officers that aren't normally doing patrols where they would be first responders and more likely to be the ones in a high risk situation than, for example, a detective.  We'd need to control for gender representation in patrol units as well.  Overall, we'd also need to control for the relative danger of different precincts - if hypothetically police officers are less likely to be women in high risk precincts, that would also skew the statistics.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian The clever thing about the design of the Ridgeway study is that it compares who actually took the shot versus who was at the scene of the shooting. Thus, lower risk precincts, detectives, desk officers, etc. shouldn't impact the result. If women happen to be underrepresented in high risk precincts, they'll also be underrepresented in being at the scene of a shooting, thus the ratio is maintained. There are still possible confounding issues as far as victims possibly being more aggressive toward male officers, or female officers being posted to less dangerous parts of the scene.

Comment: Or indeed male officers being on the scene earlier or for longer? (And of course there's a difference between officers doing crowd control and those storming a building.)

Comment: I suspect that the proportion of people killed by police or other specialized officers who are killed by SWAT teams is rather low, judging from reading news reports about officer involved shootings. Traffic stops, being the nearest officer on patrol to respond, and routine arrest warrant execution and/or things like routine evictions make up a pretty big share of all police shootings. Likewise, detectives usually come in once all the excitement is over and try to figure out what happened.

Comment: @LambdaCalc Another confounding question is who was responsible for actually dealing with hostiles.  So for example if SWAT is called in to a hostage situation there likely are already cops on the scene.  however, the SWAT team is the one expected to deal with the hostage takers, other officers may be 'on the scene' but it's reasonable to suspect they wouldn't be the one making a lethal shot, it's not really why they are there.  Thus there could still be a skew in sex of people who would be seen as responsible for using lethal means on scene vs those on scene who aren't expected to take a shot

Comment: @ohwilleke *never* use presence in the news as an indicator for actual frequency.  The media reports on what it thinks is interesting, not on what is statistically frequent.  The media doesn't care if SWAT shoots, but doesn't kill, a man resisting arrest because that doesn't stir up outrage in their audience.  The media will pick complicated or clearly wrong shootings, and only lethal ones, to talk about.  In reality I suspect SWAT is involved in majority of lethal shootings, though I sadly was not able to find a proper study on frequency of swat vs non-swat police shootings.

Comment: @dsollen The Denver Post in Colorado, and the Washington Post, nationally, maintain nearly complete and comprehensive compilations of officer involved shootings that are more complete than the official statistics which many department neglect to complete or fully report.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason to doubt the results of this study, though I'll admit I haven't done due diligence and critically examined their methodology (subtle methodological errors are the main source of misinformation in academic journal papers...). It also conforms to population norms, in which men are far more likely to commit violent crimes than women, by factors ranging from 2:1 to 4:1. See [FBI stats](https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2012/crime-in-the-u.s.-2012/tables/42tabledatadecoverviewpdf/table_42_arrests_by_sex_2012.xls) and [this law review](https://law.jrank.org/pages/1250/Gender-Crime-Differences-between-male-female-offending-patterns.htmlhttps://).

I suspect the somewhat larger '6 times' factor in policing is due to:

- A general tendency among female officers to communicate and de-escalate in tense situations, where male officers first tend to try to establish dominance and control
- The comparatively low numbers of female officers, and the relative newness of women in policing, which speaks to a more idealism among female officers than male officers

Comment: “I suspect the somewhat larger ‘6 times’ factor in policing is due to:” What makes you suspect this? What evidence do you have to back this up? Right now those two bullet points look somewhat sexist and also have zero proof.

Comment: @EkadhSingh: Common sense and an extensive exposure to the social psychological literature are really all the justification I need for those bullet points. Do you actually have reason to disagree with either point?

Comment: Well one could argue that not many women want to become police officers in the first place, and the few that do decide to take on the job are more motivated to act according to what they think an ideal police officer should act.

Comment: Or maybe female police officers simply don't deal with extremely dangerous situations as often as male officers. Boys are often taught to treat girls more softly, so it's possible female police officers get "assigned" less dangerous tasks in general. See https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15614263.2018.1468258

Comment: @TedWrigley I somewhat disagree with 1st point (as of now). Also, you were already required to back up what you say in answers (see [this](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-we-have-a-back-it-up-rule-for-answers) and also [this](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/why-do-we-need-references))

Comment: @TedWrigley here’s some evidence that the second point is (kinda? You said “relative newness” which can be interpreted many different ways) false ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_policing_in_the_United_States) site says women have been in the police force for 131-ish years, and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police#United_States) site says the US police force has been around for 230 years, I wouldn’t call that relative newness. As for the first bullet point, as far as I can tell, you’re correct. I still believe you should cite sources, but I’ll stop arguing that for now :)

Comment: Pretty misandrist answer tbh.  Could the violent crime rate gender differences be that the criminal justice system is systemically sexist and railroads men, using the same logic that says the criminal justice system is systemically racist?  Remember, the measured value is convictions by a fallible jury, not word-of-god.  And I can make just compelling and unsubstantiated claims as bullet 1 as well.  Maybe women kill less because the criminals they fight win and escape before the confrontation even gets to lethal levels?

Comment: No, the measured values are the demographics of police involved in use of force deaths.  There is no indication of any of these resulting in convictions.

Comment: @Dave I was talking about his stat that men commit more violent crime.

Comment: @Dave: You're welcome to make that argument — it's a common practice in the academic community to question the methodology of research, to find erroneous assumptions and such — but that doesn't absolve you from dealing with evidence. There are statistics for arrests and other police interactions that *do not* lead to conviction, you know, and while studies on race show that *any* police interaction is far more likely to end a minority to jail than a caucasian (e.g., it used to be that 70% of cocaine arrests were suburban whites, while 90% of convictions were urban blacks) (...)

Comment: @Dave: that is not so for gender. setting aside a couple of crimes (like simple assault and robbery) women are far less likely to be detained or arrested than men.

Comment: @TedWrigley More sexism, great.  Maybe the police are biased against men, and thus women get away with warnings for things that men would get arrested for?

Comment: @Ryan_L: (shrug) Maybe. But again, that's something you'd have to demonstrate with evidence. The standard view in academia (as of now) is that males are significantly more prone to the more extreme forms of violence than women. Could be the biology of testosterone; could be social conditioning; could be other things. but the evidence as given heavily leans towards that conclusion. If you want to change that academic view, merely raising questions isn't sufficient. You have to go out and show something different.

Comment: I wonder if differences in assigned beats has an impact in officers use of force.   Is an officer who has spent a lot of time in the hood more or less likely to go fir a gun than an officer who works his time in say suburbia?

Comment: @GarretGang probably also depends on who they've worked with in the past.  Imagine being a new recruit and an old timer tells you about the guy EMT's resuscitated who then started shooting at them.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8k4L97igDjY

Comment: @Ryan_L I was thinking of the fact that  female officers are usually assigned to safer beats then male officers. Safer beasts =lower chance of violent confrontation =less likely to use a gun.